# Redirect the iis http address of two domains with the same reference to non-www https

Tags: web, redirect, https, iis-10

I have two domains. Both read from the same source. That is, the path of their files on the server is the same with same web.config file. I want both of them to be redirect to the HTTPS path without WWW, regardless of the conditions that are called in the URL. Similar to below

1. HTTP to HTTPS
2. WWW to non-WWW

for example.com and example.co

I tried to use the below code:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS without www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Special case for HTTPS with www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But this code cannot be considered for both domains com and co. Because it redirects only to the com domain.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. "But this code cannot be considered for both domains com and co. Because it redirects only to the com domain", what does this mean? Please post more details information about your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I have two domains that are defined in iis in the binding of both domains from a common source. As you know, when redirect is used in iis, it is registered in the web.config file. I want to change the code so that it applies to both domains. It means that all statuses will be redirected to https://example.(de/co).

Comment: You have two different domain names (example.com and example.co) bound to the same site, right? Please correct me if I understand wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the file path of both domains is the same. And they read the same common web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the two different domain names into two rules, and add the full hostname to your rules, which will trigger your rule for a specific domain only:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
     <rule name="Redirect example.com to HTTPS without www" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example.com$" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
     </rule>

     <rule name="Redirect example.co to HTTPS without www" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example.co$" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.co/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
     </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: This code cannot redirect https : // www . example.(com or co) to https : // example.(com or co)

Comment: Please try using FRT to trace rewrite rules, you can see how the rules are used internally. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules